# geting multiplier value of hour/day/week from integer containing seconds

Tags: php

I am storing a total number of seconds in a field like so:

Multiplier x Hour in seconds (60*60)
or
Multiplier x Day in seconds (60*60*24)
or
Multiplier x Week in seconds (60*60*24*7)

The user can enter a multiplier (an integer value). Hour, Day, and Week are fixed values, so the user can select only one of those options.

The API i'm provided with only allows storing of this integer value as total number of seconds.

When retrieving this value, how would it be possible to determine what was the Multiplier value they entered and wether it falls under Hour, Day, or Week?

I'm currently developing this piece in PHP. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does *java* and *c* have to do with it? << aside from that I really have no idea what you are asking, some concrete, code based, examples would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I can suggest a function like this:-

```
/**
 * Given number of seconds will calculate if likely
 * multiplier is weeks, days, hours or seconds
 *
 * @param int $period
 * @return string representing possible chosen multiplier
 */
function getMultiplier($period)
{
    $hour = 60*60;
    $day = $hour * 24;
    $week = $day * 7;

    if($period >= $week && $period % $week == 0){
        return $period/$week . " weeks";
    }
    if($period >= $day && $period % $day == 0){
        return $period/$day . " days";
    }
    if($period >= $hour && $period % $hour == 0){
        return $period/$hour . " hours";
    }
    return "$period seconds";
}
```

Use it like this:-

```
echo getMultiplier(60 * 60 * 23);
```

Will output

> 23 hours

Comment: Awesome work vascowhite. It works great!

Comment: I only tested it with a couple of edge cases, but hopefully it should catch everything.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the multiplier has to be an integer - you can then check divisibility of week and day to see if that's what the entered.

If (total_seconds / seconds_in_week) is an integer, they probably picked "week"
If (total_seconds / seconds_in_day) is an integer, they probably picked "day"
Otherwise, they definitely picked seconds.

Even if they did pick something like 14 days, it'll probably be better off displayed in weeks anyway.

Comment: Use `if(total_seconds % seconds_in_week == 0)` and save the check for an integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot sam and vascowhite! I wrote it in javascript at the same time as waiting for a reply and ended up writting exactly what you guys suggested! Works great. Thanks.